# Що таке "батір"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми, діалекти

Нещодавно побував в селі на Львівщині, де один дідусь, коли його внук розбив вікно сараю, назвав його "батіром". Стало цікаво, що це за слово, а тому вирішив загуглити. Перше посилання в Гуглі була на СУМ - слово "[батир](http://sum.in.ua/s/batyr)", однак воно означає:

> У деяких східних народів — герой, хоробра людина.

А тому я сумніваюся, що це визначення підходить у цьому випадку. На жаль, ніякої інформації про те, що це слово означає мені не вдалося знайти. Можливо хтось знає, що означає це слово?

Особисто моя думка - це щось на кшталт слова "шибеник".

Comment: Змінив на посилання, силка - калька російської ccылка.

Comment: Навіть јакшчо калька, то правильіше _зсилка._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Відомішим написом є [*батяр*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8).

> Назва *батяр*, імовірно, виникла від угорського [*betyar*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bety%C3%A1r#Hungarian), що означає особу, яка має дивні погляди і робить непередбачувані вчинки, авантюриста, гульвісу.

Инші словники:

- [Тлумачний словник-довідник гуцульських говірок](http://194.44.152.155/elib/local/sk806506.pdf#page=7)

  > *бакеретво* розбишацтво, гультяйство
  >
  > *бакір*, ***батір*** здріб. *бакірина*, *батірина* батяр, гультяй, розбишака, шибеник, волоцюга, розпусник, авантюрист
  >
  > *бакірувати,* *батірувати* вести гультяйське життя
- [Етнос. Соціум. Культура: регіональний аспект](http://194.44.152.155/elib/local/sk715358.pdf#page67)

  > ***батір*** — гультяй, волоцюга